Symmetrizability and Semimetrizability of one-point compactifications
The one-point compactification of a metrizable space need not be metrizable. For instance, the one-point compactification of the metric fan is not metrizable because it is not even $T_2$ (since the base space is not locally compact).
However, it is semimetrizable. Recall that a semimetric is a reflexive and symmetric function $s:X^2\to[0,\infty)$ such that the semimetric balls form a neighborhood base at each point. (In particular, semimetrizable topologies are first-countable, though these semimetric ball neighborhoods need not be open neighborhoods.)
The compactified fan can be defined as $\omega^2\cup\{\infty_x,\infty_y\}$ such that each point of $\omega^2$ is isolated, neighborhoods of $\infty_x$ contain all but finitely-many columns, and neighborhoods of $\infty_y$ contain all but finitely-many rows. Then we set $s(p,p)=0$, $s(\langle m,n\rangle,\infty_x)=s(\infty_x,\langle m,n\rangle)=\frac{1}{m+1}$, $s(\langle m,n\rangle,\infty_y)=s(\infty_y,\langle m,n\rangle)=\frac{1}{n+1}$, and $s(p,q)=1$ otherwise, and can verify this forms a semimetric.
It just occurred to me that not every one-point compactification of a metrizble space semimetrizable, because it need not be first-countable: consider the one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space.
However, are they at least symmetrizable? A symmetric is a reflexive and symmetric function $s:X^2\to[0,\infty)$ such that a set is open exactly when each point has a symmetric ball centered at it and contained in the set.

I think your definition of "symmetric" is slightly off.  A symmetric $s:X^2\to[0,\infty)$ is just a function that is reflexive and symmetric. There is no connection to any a priori topology.  A space $X$ is symmetrizable if there exists a symmetric on $X$ that generates the topology in the sense that you gave.

No. The one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space is not symmetrizable either. In fact, let me prove the following, more general fact:
Theorem: If $X$ is almost discrete (i.e., $X$ has exactly one point which is non-isolated) and symmetrizable, then $X$ is semimetrizable (in particular first countable).
Proof: Let $d$ be a symmetric generating the topology on $X$. If $p \in X$ is isolated, then $\{p\}$, being open, must contain a symmetric ball around $p$, i.e., there exists $\epsilon_p > 0$ s.t. $B(p, \epsilon_p) = \{p\}$. This in particular shows symmetric balls around $p$ form a neighborhood base at $p$.
Consider, on the other hand, when $p$ is non-isolated. Recall that $d$ generating the topology means $U \subset X$ is open iff whenever $x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon_x > 0$ s.t. $B(x, \epsilon_x) \subset U$. By our previous discussion on isolated points of $X$, we see that the condition is automatically satisfied for those $x \in U$ that are isolated in $X$. Hence,

$U \subset X$ is open iff either it does not contain $p$, or there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B(p, \epsilon) \subset U$.

In particular, symmetric balls around $p$ are all open, so they form a neighborhood base at $p$. This shows $d$ is actually a semimetric for $X$ and $X$ is, in particular, semimetrizable. $\square$

Nicely put. I feel like there may be some flavor similar to https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000628/converse here (though almost discrete and F-U are orthogonal properties)

@StevenClontz I’m not sure there is much similarity beyond superficial resemblance. Almost discrete is just too special a condition. In fact, combining with T643, we see that for an almost discrete space, it is symmetrizable iff it is semimetrizable iff it is metrizable iff it is completely metrizable iff it is $T_1$ and first countable.

Indeed. And π-Base, Search for $T_1$+Fréchet Urysohn+Almost discrete+~First countable demonstrates we cannot weaken first countable to Frechet-Urysohn here.

@StevenClontz True. The equivalences above seem the best that can be obtained.

The result

Every symmetrizable Fréchet–Urysohn space is semimetrizable.

is wrong. (At one point pi-base had this incorrect result as T628.)
I will show by a counterexample that the original symmetric does not work and present a complete counterexample respectively.
I will also show that the result becomes true if one adds the US condition to the hypotheses.
Original symmetric does not work
Consider $X = \{0\} \cup (\color{red}0, \color{red}1) \cup (\color{blue}0, \color{blue}1)$, where distance defines as follows:

$d(0, \color{red}b) = d(\color{red}a, \color{blue}b) = b$,
$d(0, \color{blue}b) = 1$,
$d(\color{red}a, \color{red}b) = d(\color{blue}a, \color{blue}b) = \left| a - b \right|$.

Then each point has the following neighborhood basis:

$0$: $U_n = \{0\} \cup (\color{red}0, \color{red}{\frac 1n}) \cup (\color{blue}0, \color{blue}{\frac 1n})$,
$\color{red}p$: $V_n = (\color{red}{p-\frac 1n}, \color{red}{p+\frac 1n}) \cup (\color{blue}0, \color{blue}{\frac 1n})$,
$\color{blue}p$: $W_n = (\color{blue}{p-\frac 1n}, \color{blue}{p+\frac 1n})$.

Obviously, all $U_n, V_n, W_n$ are open. Let $U$ be any open subset, then $U \cap (\color{blue}0, \color{blue}1)$ is open in $(\color{blue}0, \color{blue}1)$ because it is metrizable in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ region.
Suppose there exists $\color{red}{\text{red}~p} \in U$, then $B_\varepsilon(\color{red}p) \subseteq U$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$, we know that $U$ contains $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ points.
Similarly, if $0 \in U$, then $U$ must contains $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ points. So $X$ is symmetrizable with symmetric $d$.

Clearly $X$ is first countable hence Fréchet–Urysohn. But the symmetric $d$ is not a semimetric, because $0 \in \operatorname{cl}(\color{blue}0, \color{blue}1)$ but $d \bigl( 0, (\color{blue}0, \color{blue}1) \bigr) = \inf\limits_{\color{blue}0 < \color{blue}p < \color{blue}1} d(0, \color{blue}p) = 1$.
Plus, $X$ is not US since every point in $\{0\} \cup (\color{red}0, \color{red}1)$ is the limit of sequence $x_n = \color{blue}{\frac 1n}$.
A complete counterexample
Take $X = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3$ be disjoint union of three circles $S^1$, let $f \colon S^1 \to S^1$ be any everywhere surjection function, e.g., Conway base 13 function.
Denote $d_{S^1}$ as the Euclidean distance on $S^1$, $$ D(x, y) = \begin{cases} + \infty & y = f(x), \\ d_{S^1} \bigl( y, f(x) \bigr) & y \neq f(x), \end{cases} \quad x, y \in S^1. $$
Then we define a symmetric $d$ as follows: $$ d(x, y) = \begin{cases} d_{S^1}(x, y) & x, y \in C_i \text{ for some } i = 1, 2, 3, \\ D(x, y) & x \in C_i, y \in C_{i+1} \text { for some } i = 1, 2, 3. \end{cases} $$ (index are treated modulo $3$)
Consider the topology $d$ induces (every symmetric can induce a symmetric space, but not semimetric space), let $U$ be an open set, $U_i = U \cap C_i$.

$U_i$ is a Euclidean open subset of $C_i$,
If $U_i \neq \varnothing$, then $U_{i+1} \neq \varnothing$, and vice versa.
Let $x \in U_i$, then there exists an interval $I$ of $C_i$ such that $I \subset U_i$, since $f(I) = S^1$, we know for each $y \in U_{i+1}$, there exists a punctured neighborhood lie in $U_{i+1}$.

So $C_{i+1} \setminus U_{i+1}$ is discrete, hence finite.



From the above analysis we know that the topology of $X$ is coarser than cofinite topology on $X$. But symmetric spaces are $T_1$. So this topology is exactly “Cofinite topology on a continuum-sized set”!

Obviously, cofinite topology on $\mathbb R$ is not Semimetrizable (since it is not first countable), we've find a counterexample (it is very unexpectedly Symmetrizable!)
Fixing by adding US property
A space $X$ is called US if every convergent sequence in $X$ has exactly one limit.  This is a property intermediate between $T_2$ and $T_1$.
By adding US to the hypotheses of T628, the result becomes correct, namely,

Theorem: Every symmetrizable Fréchet–Urysohn US space is semimetrizable.

Theorem 1.2.8 (4) ⇒ (1) in Generalized Metric Spaces and Mappings shows the result under the stronger hypothesis that the space is Hausdorff, instead of US. (The Hausdorff condition is assumed for the whole book.)  But we can prove the result with the US hypothesis by slightly changing the argument as follows:
Proof of Theorem:
Suppose $X$ is a Fréchet–Urysohn US space and $X$ is symmetrizable with symmetric $d$. If $A \subseteq X$ and $x \in \operatorname{cl} A \setminus A$, then there is a sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $A$ converging to $x$. It follows from the lemma below that $d(x_n, x) \to 0$, therefore $d(x, A) = 0$, which implies $d$ is a semi-metric.

Lemma: Let $(X, d)$ be a symmetrizable space with symmetric $d$ and suppose $X$ is US. Given a sequence of points $\left\{ x_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and a point $x \in X$, then $$ x_n \to x \iff d(x_n, x) \to 0. $$


($\Leftarrow$) Sufficiency part:
This part does not require the US condition. Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $x$, it follows from the symmetrizable property that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq U$, then there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n \in B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq U$ for all $n > N$.

($\Rightarrow$) Necessity part:
Suppose $x_n \to x$ but $d(x_n, x) \nrightarrow 0$. By taking subsequence, we can assume $d(x_n, x) \geq \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Let $A = \left\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \right\}$.
For every other $y \notin A \cup \{x\}$, $y$ is not the limit of the sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ (by US).
In fact, $A \cup \{x\}$ is sequentially closed (see the comments below for details).  Since every symmetrizable space is sequential (see here), it follows that $A \cup \{x\}$ is closed, and hence $\operatorname{cl} A = A \cup \{x\}$.
Hence, symmetrizability gives us $d(y, A) \geq d(y, \operatorname{cl} A) > 0$. Moreover, $d(x, A) \geq \varepsilon$ by construction, we obtain that $A$ is closed, contradict with $\operatorname{cl} A = A \cup \{x\}$.



Also, the definition of a symmetric does not allow $\infty$. But that can be easily fixed by changing $\infty$ to any fixed positive number. Otherwise, the argument looks correct. This is quite surprising, that the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ should be symmetrizable. Very nice result!

Why $A \cup {x}$ is sequentially closed? This is a simple but tedious deduction:

Let ${y_n}$ be any sequence on $A\cup{x}$, then either of the following is true:

Some element appears infinite many times:
Then it contains a constant subsequence, which has the limit equal to that constant in $A\cup{x}$,
Each element appears finite many times:
Thus it contains a subsequence ${z_k}$ such that $z_k=x_{n_k}$ for each $k$ and $n_1 < n_2 < \dots$, where $z_k\to x$ by property of subsequence.

In either case, ${y_n}$ contains a subsequence which converge to point in $A\cup{x}$, so ${y_n}$ cannot have a limit outside of $A \cup {x}$ by US property.

Very ingenious proof that the cofinite topology on $\mathbb R$ is symmetrizable (+1)

Yes, it's my typo.

@KitsuneKiriha Also, in part 1, is the formula for $U_n$ correct?  The distance from $0$ to a blue point is always $1$, so there should be no blue interval as part of $U_n$ ?

No problem because in definition on symmetrizable space balls needn't be a neighborhood basis.

I guess it was not clear to me.  You say "Then each point has the following neighborhood basis".  The word "Then" seems to imply that the $U_n$, etc. are defined based on the preceding paragraph.  Or is that not the case?

Symmetric indeed can induce a topology but the “neighborhood balls” are usually not directly corresponding to the local basis.

Thanks.  That's an important point.  I understand now.

I've realized that one can prove the following, even more general fact:
Theorem: If $X$ is almost discrete and sequential, then $X$ is Fréchet Urysohn.
This Theorem generalizes the result in my previous answer. Indeed, a symmetrizable space is always sequential (see T626 in pi-Base). So, an almost discrete symmetrizable $X$ is Fréchet Urysohn, per Theorem. A Fréchet Urysohn symmetrizable $X$ is always semimetrizable (see T628 in pi-Base), so the result in my previous answer follows.
Edit: In light of @KitsuneKiriha’s answer that the original T628 is wrong, let me note here that the Theorem is still a generalization of the result in my previous answer, since symmetrizable spaces are $T_1$ (see T625 in pi-Base) and almost discrete $T_1$ spaces are $T_2$ (see here), thus in particular US.
Proof of Theorem: Let $A \subset X$ and $K$ be the sequential closure of $A$ (i.e., the set of all limits of sequences in $A$). We need to show $K$ is closed. Let $p \in X$ be the unique non-isolated point. Then $\overline{A}$ is either $A$ or $A \cup \{p\}$, so $K$ is either $A$ or $A \cup \{p\}$ as well. In the first case, $A$ is sequentially closed and thus closed, as $X$ is sequential, so $K = A$ is closed. In the second case, $K = A \cup \{p\}$ is always closed. $\square$
